# How do I repair an invalid boot.ini without the Windows XP CD?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I need to repair an invalid `boot.ini` file, but I don't have a Windows XP CD.

Does anyone know how to repair the `boot.ini` file, **without** a Windows XP CD?

Answer (score 4):

You can boot from an Ubuntu Live CD and edit the file C:\boot.ini, You just open it in notepad and this is an example of it's structure:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=5
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition" /fastdetect
```

Answer (score 0):

From ["Invalid Boot.ini" error messages when you start your computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330184):

> To resolve this issue, start the
>   computer from the Windows XP CD, start
>   the Recovery Console, and then use the
>   "Bootcfg.exe /rebuild" tool to rebuild
>   the Boot.ini file.

See the above article for step-by-step instructions.

EDIT:

You can use the [DiskInternals Boot CD](http://www.diskinternals.com/boot-cd/) to boot and do some repair operations.

If you need an Emergency Boot CD (XP SP2 Pro & XP SP2 Home), there is apparently also a mini-iso [here](http://www.answersthatwork.com/Downright_pages/Boot_CD_and_Boot_Disk_Images_and_ISO_free_downloads.htm), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: It was stated in the question that the poster did not have a Windows XP CD.

Comment: OK - fixed.   (because required at least 15 characters)